# Linux UTM VM Hardware Clock is Incorrect

Tags: linux, virtual-machine, date, hardware, clock

My machine natively runs MacOS Ventura 13.3.1. I am using UTM to run 5.14.8-arch1-1. I am on PST. The output of `sudo hwclock --verbose` is as follows:

```
hwclock from util-linux 2.37.2
...
Hardware clock is on UTC time
ASsuming hardware clock is kept in UTC time.
...
Time read from Hardware Clock: 2023/05/18 19:35:23
...
Time since last adjustment is -24880 seconds
Calculated Hardware Clock drift is 0.000 seconds
2023-05-18 12:36:39.918344-07:00
```

This was done at 2023/05/18 19:35:23-07:00 time, or PST. I attempted to set the hardware clock manually correctly using `sudo hwclock --set`.

The problem seems to be that the VM receives hardware clock as local time (from my MacOS machine) and then assumes it is UTC so it converts it to local time (which it already was in).

When I reset manually using `sudo hwclock --set` or `date -s`, it resets back upon a `shutdown`. How do I fix this?